# Check simple human fetus answers

Tags: human-biology, homework, reproduction, sexual-reproduction

Based on this image and questions, could someone please check my answers?

**Question 1:** At which one of the following points will the blood passing the point be more oxygenated after birth than before it?

I would think at point P.

**Question 2:** At which one of the following points will the blood passing the point be significantly less oxygenated after birth than before it?

I think point L, because the blood should not lose any more oxygen as it travels through veins and the heart to the lungs.

[image: The fetus image]

Comment: Please see this sites policy for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions. Among other things, such questions must be appropriately tagged. Thanks!

Comment: 1) It was not a homework question, but a practice question to demonstrate how a platform works before I take an online quiz, for which I have already included my thought process instead of asking for the answer outright. 2) I am unsure with which keywords to tag this as I am new to the community?

Comment: 1) Please review the criteria on the page I listed. 2) homework is a tag, as is described on the that same page. In addition, please take the [tour] and to read [help] pages such as [ask]. The [meta] pages also contain many questions and answers about the expectations this community has for users. Please also consider whether [MedicalSciences.SE] is a better fit, but please do **not** crosspost, instead request migration. Also note that that site also has stringent expectations about prior research.

Comment: Well I added that tag, and I made a few changes since my responses would not have made sense.

Comment: Thank you for all of the downvotes, what a welcoming community. I thought it was just computer scientists with a toxicity problem.

Comment: I'm sorry you've found your first experience here unpleasant and I do understand that being downvoted can feel like a personal attack. However, downvotes are merely an evaluation of how appropriate a particular question is for this site. Your choice to view  that as "toxic" leads me to strongly encourage you to familiarize yourself with this sites [help] before your next post. Good luck!

Comment: @tyersome Sorry, I should have perhaps not worded that so harshly. Basically, where can I ask these style of questions to not upset people here? It was not even a homework question, but an example question for the official exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1 I would agree with "P"

For question 2 the answer would be "M" although an argument could be made for "O". Consider that *before* birth "M" should be the points were blood contains the most oxygen since it is coming directly form the oxygen exchange While *after* birth it contains the least amount of oxygen becasue that exchange is lost and it instead only receiving blood from the body where most of the oxygen has been extracted. So the change at that point is about as large a change as possible.  I don't know how you got "L" it should have little to no change in oxygen content as both before and after birth it is receiving low oxygen blood from the body.

Comment: My point of view was L, M, and O are all equally deoxygenated after it goes through the capillaries at the very bottom of the image and should remain the same until the reach the lungs after birth. However, since the question focuses on AFTER birth then I agree it must be M because it has the biggest change from oxygenated to deoxygenated when the mother's maternal artery is disconnected.